# How to tell whether two functions are linearly independent by inspection of their graphs?

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's known that linearly independent vectors means that they are not parallel.  But with functions, how do the graphs of linearly independent functions look like?

For instance, how can I know by inspection that $p_1(x) = 1-x^2$ and $p_2(x)= 2-x^2$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Geometrically, if $p_2(x)$ cannot be obtained from a scaling of $p_1(x)$ about the $x$-axis, then the two functions are linearly independent. Note that this geometric intuition will only work if you are only checking if **two** functions are linearly independent, like the intuition you wrote for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (for example, three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ may not be mutually parallel, but they must form a linearly dependent basis).

Answer (score 1):

Vector spaces are abstract entities in mathematics, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and even a little $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are intuitive and rich in geometry, however vector spaces like $P_{n}(\mathbb{R}), M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$,etc, are difficult to analyze geometrically.

For this, it is best to obtain the coordinates of the vectors and then analyze the geometry of the vectors.

Note that
$$[1-x^{2}]_{B}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$[2-x^{2}]_{B}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
considering vector space $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, $S=\{1-x^{2},2-x^{2}\}$ and a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and since that $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, so you can get a geometric idea of the linear independence dependence of this set of vectors you mention.